# How to get the app store icon glass effect on a webpage?

Tags: iphone, html, effect, aero-glass

Is there any simple way to display the icon for my iphone apps on my webpage the same way they look in the appstore (i.e. with the glass effect and preferably with reflection)? I have very little experience in web coding so some sample code that I could just copy and paste would be great if this is possible. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Not the glass effect, but you can get the rounded corners and the reflection by using this CSS:

```
    -webkit-box-reflect:below 0px -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom,
      from(transparent), color-stop(0.8, transparent), to(rgba(0,0,0,0.5)));
    -webkit-border-radius:12px;
    -moz-border-radius:12px;
```

It only works for the reflection in WebKit-browsers (not yet all) and the rounded corners work in FireFox as well.

Comment: I would like to accept both answers here, since what I actually did was download the image from flavorstudios, fix it up, then use this reflection code. I picked this as the best since the site is a bit annoying in that you have to crop the image yourself and then redo the transparency. It takes < 1 min to do this but I had to base the choice on something. Thanks a lot to both of you.